# Unable to get connection to mysql database in netbeans java web application

Tags: mysql, servlets, netbeans

I am new to web development to java. I am writing this basic java web application that is going to store customer information into a database. I use the MVC-2 architecture. My Jsp sends a request to a servlet that in turn tries instatiates a bean an inserts that object into a database. 
When i try to connect to the database (in debugging mode) the connection variable returns empty. So data cannot be inserted.

This is the class that makes connections to the db

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package customer;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class DatabaseOperations implements Serializable 
{
    private static Connection connection;
    public DatabaseOperations()
    {
        try
        {
            String username = "root";
            String password = "root";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);

            System.out.println("Database connection established");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

This is the method that adds a customer to the db

```
public void addCustomer(CustomerBean customer) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseOperations db = new DatabaseOperations();
        connection = DatabaseOperations.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        String query = "insert into customer (name, address, phone, email) "
                + "values (" + customer.name + ","
                + customer.address + ","
                + customer.phone + ","
                + customer.email + "," + ")";

        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }
```

and finally this is the servlet where i call the method to add a customer

```
   /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package customer;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import customer.CustomerBean;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

    /**
     *
     * @author 
     */
    public class CustomerServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /**
         * Processes requests for both HTTP
         * <code>GET</code> and
         * <code>POST</code> methods.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            CustomerBean customer = new CustomerBean();
            try {
                out.println("tests");

                customer.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
                customer.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
                customer.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
                customer.setPhone(request.getParameter("phone"));

/************** ADD CUSTOMER TO DB HERE***********************/
                customer.addCustomer(customer);

                request.setAttribute("cust", customer);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {            
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Also i will like to specify that my netbeans IDE connects well to mysql database because i can create table and insert data from the services tab in netbeans.

Comment: Did you have a question? Or were you just giving a status report on your current development efforts? Is ALL of that code relevant to the problem, or do you think it might be narrowed down a bit, like, where you are actually getting the database connection. Is there a way to test whether that was successful. Is there an exception or error message being displayed, or is this just "not working". Maybe the problem is in the call to `getConnection` method. Is that a static method, or is it an instance method? (Should you be calling the getConnection method of `db`)?

Comment: i have a problem. all the code is pertinent to the problem. The get connection method is static. My problem here is that whenever i instatiate Database operations, i expect a connection to be made to the database and i expect that connection to be in the connection instance variable. but it is not there. When i run the debugger, it skips the statement "connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);" s i guess this is where the error comes from

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to point out that your code is open to SQL injection.  Personally, I'm a fan of procedures, so I'll recommend that: you should create a procedure in mysql to insert a new record, and then provide that sproc with the arguments (name, address, etc).

As for the problem at hand: After your `statement.executeUpdate` line, try closing the connection.  Also, extract the `Class.forName` to your main method.  It should only be executed once.  Also, remove the `.newInstance()` off of that once you have done so.

If all that doesn't work, extract the entire connection out to a globally accessible static variable **and do not assign to it more than once**.  See if your program works then.  If not, you have a separate problem.